# Timeout for a listenning socket (Windows)

Tags: windows, sockets, timeout, listen

does anyone know if you can set a timeout for a listening socket?
I know that you can use a timeout  for a send/recv action with SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO (through setsockopt) but in my case I need to set that timeout for a socket in a listen state. If no connection is established in X time, I closed the socket. Do you know any socket option to get that?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use the `select()` function which is for that purpose. If the socket is read(able) means that you can use the `accept()` without blocking. If `select()` return 0 means the timeout has elapsed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set `SO_RCVTIMEO` and it will timeout the `accept()` method.